# Prevent Jersey responding to an API call when Accept is not application/json

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

I'm currently using Jersey 1.18 (for legacy reasons).

I have an api endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/something")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final Response doMyThing(final @Context HttpServletRequest req, ...) {
...
}
```

But it's currently responding to calls where `Accepts` is set to `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3`

I want Jersey to ignore it unless `Accept` is `application/json`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use a Jersey filter.

Comment: That won't work where I have two servlets that respond to the same endpoint but with different content types (eg: text/html = react front end and application/json = jersey-managed backend).